# Crossedbox symbol without the box

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I'm looking for a symbol looking as the `\Crossedbox` from `marvosym` without the box around the cross.

I looked http://www.rpi.edu/dept/arc/training/latex/LaTeX_symbols.pdf and detextify without seeing anything.

Have you anything that could help me?

Comment: You are aware that there is a more recent version (well, from 2009) of this list?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer No and thanks to this list I've found what I want `:-)` Thank you

Comment: Perhaps you should add it as answer

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I add the comment before `;-)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Christian Hupfer I found this new list: http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-letter.pdf

And found the solution I wanted `\ding{55}`  from `table 251`

Comment: Comments can't really upvoted :-P